# Is it possible to perform any action while installing apk?

Tags: android, sql, apk

I want to run the sql script (.sql file) while installing the apk then after installing an apk show the data  on UI.
Is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Particularly on Android 3.1, nothing in your app will run until the user taps on the launcher icon, or some other app on the device specifically runs some of your code (e.g., if you are a plugin to some host app).

Moreover, what you are asking for is the wrong answer for your problem, anyway. Your database can be deleted at any point by the user, via the Clear Data button in your app's screen in Settings. Hence, it is not just when your app is installed (or even on the first run of your app) that you have to deal with setting up your database.

A better solution for this pattern is to create the actual database (rather than a `.sql` file) and [use `SQLiteAssetHelper` to unpack the database](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) if there is no database already.